# Check how many variables equal zero with php

Tags: php, variables

I have numerous variables and I need to print a numeric value for how many of these variables are equal to zero:

```
$var1 = '2';
$var2 = '0';
$var3 = '4';

//check how many variables = 0
$zeros = ?

//should be a numeric value this example should print '1'
echo $zeros
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: an array would be a lot better than separate variables

Comment: better use [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for that, its not really hard to learn

Comment: I ended up using arrays, thank you for these responses, my solution is below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put all of my variables into an array, looped with foreach and added to the $zeros variable:

```
$values = array('0' => $var1, '1' => $var2, '2' => $var3);

$zeros = 0;

foreach($values as $v) {
    if($v === '0')
    $zeros++;
 }

echo $zeros;
```

I found this was an easy solution, thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 3):

This gets a list of all defined variables, and counts how many are `=== 0` and excludes the `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE` globals.

If you define this code in a function, then only the variables in that scope are counted.

```
<?php 

$value = 0;
$var   = 1;
$test  = false;
$nine  = 0;
$zero  = 9;

$zeroes = 1;  // set to 1 so we don't count this

$vars = get_defined_vars();

foreach($vars as $var) {
    if (is_array($var) && (
      isset($var['_GET']) || isset($var['_POST']) ||
      isset($var['_COOKIE']))
    ) {
        continue;  // don't count superglobal arrays
    }

    if ($var === 0) $zeroes++;
}

$zeroes -= 1;  // subtract the initial value

echo "There are $zeroes zero values.";  // There are 2 zero values.
```

EDIT:  It could be modified to be a function that would work recursively if you needed to check the values of arrays for example.  You could call it from the global scope like this:

```
$zeroes = countZero(get_defined_vars());
```

And then the function could detect arrays and call itself until it has searched all vars.

Comment: I am actually using some GET variables!

Comment: In that case, the recursive function option sounds like the way to go, and delete the `isset($var['_GET'])` check so it will not ignore $_GET variables.

Answer (score 0):

`if($var1 == 0) $zeros++;` repeat for var2, 3, etc.

Use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to generate variables from a string if they all follow the `varX` pattern where `X` is a number.

```
$var1 = '2';
$var2 = '0';
$var3 = '4';
$zeros = 0;

for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
  $var = ${'var' . $i};
  if($var == 0) $zeros ++;
}

echo $zeros;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the purpose of what you are trying to achieve here and maybe I am misunderstanding the need but the following yet simple code does it:

```
$var1 = '2';
$var2 = '0';
$var3 = '4';

$zeros = ($var1 =='0')?1:0 + ($var2 =='0')?1:0 + ($var3 =='0')?1:0;
echo $zeros
```

Basically I nested [ternaly conditional expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) instead of using regular if then elses.